# Eclipse CDT fails to run compiled executable in Windows with error "terminated, exit value: <some number>"

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, runtime-error, eclipse-cdt

I just reinstalled Windows on my machine. Before that, I was using the `Eclipse CDT IDE` for Windows (64-bit) with MinGW compiler suite (downloaded using mingw-get). Everything worked perfectly fine before the reinstall.

After the installation I tried to compile and run my C++ projects, but I always got the `terminated, exit value: <some number>` error in the console, even for a `Hello World!` project. I also got an error saying the `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is missing from my computer when I tried to run the executable from the command line.

So I uninstalled MinGW and tried again and it did not work. I completely removed anything related to MinGW from my system, I removed Eclipse, deleted every workspace, cleaned everything (or at least I think). Then I created a fresh `Eclipse` folder, then installed the `MinGW` and created path variables. Everything looked like they have been reset and now when I try to compile and run anything, the compilations seems to work fine but running the executable is still not possible. I still get the same error on every launch. Cleaning the project did not work either. I tried several other workarounds both from Stack Overflow and other sources but they did not work for me either and I am clueless at this point and stuck.

I would really appreciate any help regarding this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like, using debug inside eclipse ends up with the correct progression of the code but running the executable directly does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you did not properly add the mingw/bin folder to your PATH variable. libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll should be in there.

compiling should work, because eclipse autodetects your mingw installation. but when you try to run your program it just searches the PATH variable and it´s own directory for the dll and fails to find it

Comment: is libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll in your mingw/bin folder? can you run g++.exe out of a command promt at c:\

Comment: Yes the file exists. Now I tried to compile using the command line again and it failed. Then I manually entered the path command ("path C:\MinGW\bin\") and tried compiling afterwards and it succeded. Also the executable does not end up with an error anymore. But, when I close the command line, compile the code again from inside Eclipse, it succeeds to compile but cannot run the executable. Then when I reopen a command line and run the executable from there I get the same error. But, if I manually run path again it runs perfectly fine. I think you are right, but how can I fix this?

Comment: I think I did a mistake when placing `path` variables. I deleted the `MinGW` entry and added it again, now everything works fine. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

The missing libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is a telltale sign of a different, and possibly wrong (mismatched pieces?) MinGW installation (or of CDT failing at its autodetection tricks).

I suggest compiling something simple from the command line and then something less simple with Make to validate the MinGW installation before involving Eclipse CDT.