# Running simple C++ program in Eclipse with unexpected console output

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, mingw

I'm trying to program in C++ on Eclipse, I have installed and configured MinGW, but I have a problem that I don't understand:

I have some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I can't see any output, it doesn't give me an error, but it does show some strange output on console:

```
<terminated> (exit value: -1.073.741.515) CPS:exe [C/C++ Application] C:\\ (dir)
```

This is my run configuration:
[image: run configuration]

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT fails to run compiled executable in Windows with error "terminated, exit value: <some number>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082736/eclipse-cdt-fails-to-run-compiled-executable-in-windows-with-error-terminated)

Comment: There's also this one - [Eclipse- C/C++ <terminated, exit value: -1073741515>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550496/eclipse-c-c-terminated-exit-value-1073741515) - that has the same exit value (`-1.073.741.515`).